# Cannot edit content editor

Tags: 2013, web-part, permissions

I've some problems with editing a webpart.

For example I am able to create webparts but afterwards I cannot delete them without doing it with the `?contents=1` URL addition.

I've given my account full access everywhere (+ Creat, Write, Read and what's left), though.

I tried to edit the content editor but there's no option to edit it.

I just wanted to do this simple tutorial:
http://blog.creative-sharepoint.com/2013/03/creating-a-sharepoint-2013-intranet-homepage/

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: are you able to put your page into edit mode ? Is it that you do not get the dropdown to edit the web part ?

Comment: I am able to do this. I can add WebParts or AppParts but I cannot delete them afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

Try going into Page / Edit Properties / Edit Properties, scroll to the bottom, and click the "view page in maintenance mode" option.  There your CEWPs are displayed in a list and you can delete them or reset them there.

Comment: That takes you to the URL already mentioned in the question